# Select rows that logged in 4 hours ago by timestamp

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table with which stores the last login time of users in UNIX format. I want to get the information about all those users who logged in at least 4 days ago. This is an image of the database:

[image]

I have tried this:

```
$time = sql_query("select * from ".tb()."accounts");
$pp = sql_fetch_array($time);
$tp = $pp['lastlogin'];
$ts = strtotime('-4 day',time());
$tg = $tp > $ts;
$res = sql_query("select f.fid from ".tb()."friends as f left join ".tb()."accounts as u on u.id=f.fid where f.uid='{$client['id']}' order by {$tg} desc limit 50");
```

but it does not seem to be working. Is there an easy wayto display the info of all those users who logged in more than 4 days ago?

Comment: Exactly 4 days ago, to the second? On the date that occurred 4 days ago? At least 4 days ago? Within 4 days?

Comment: Not exactly 4 days ago..!!
before 4 days ago..!!

Answer (score 2):

Select rows where the last login is more than 4 days in the past:

```
SELECT
  ...
WHERE
  FROM_UNIXTIME(lastlogin) < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL 4 DAY
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html